# How can I return multiple rows from the model same function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This code print only one row, not print all data

Model

```
public function schbysempaid($batch, $sem){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE curem=$sem AND baid=$batch");
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $querys=$this->db->query("SELECT SUM(install.adfee) as am,SUM(install.lifee) as lb,SUM(install.tfee) as tt,SUM(install.enrfee) as enr,SUM(install.refee) as re,SUM(install.spofee) as spo,SUM(install.exfee) as ex FROM stu JOIN install ON install.sid=stu.sid Where install.sid='".$row['sid']."' AND install.curem=$sem AND stu.curem=$sem AND stu.baid=$batch AND install.paid=1");
        return $querys->result_array();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public function searchsubmit()
{
        $batch=$this->input->post('srch');
        $sem=$this->input->post('srch1');
        $data['searchpaid']=$this->law_model->schbysempaid($batch, $sem);
        $this->load->view('admission/dashboard',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning result in foreach loop, instead you could save that data in array and after end of loop you can return it. check below

```
function schbysempaid($batch, $sem)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE curem=$sem AND baid=$batch");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $retArr = [];
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $querys = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(install.adfee) as am,SUM(install.lifee) as lb,SUM(install.tfee) as tt,SUM(install.enrfee) as enr,SUM(install.refee) as re,SUM(install.spofee) as spo,SUM(install.exfee) as ex FROM stu JOIN install ON install.sid=stu.sid Where install.sid='" . $row['sid'] . "' AND install.curem=$sem AND stu.curem=$sem AND stu.baid=$batch AND install.paid=1");
        $retArr[] = $querys->result_array();
    }
    return $retArr; // I am returning your data here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
return $querys->result_array();
```

to

```
$response[] = $querys->result_array();
```

**Explanation:** You are using `$querys->result_array();` inside a loop, in that case for the first iteration it return the result and skip the next iterations. So hold it in some array and return it like:

```
return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public function schbysempaid($batch, $sem){
$result = array();
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE curem=$sem AND baid=$batch");
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $querys=$this->db->query("SELECT SUM(install.adfee) as am,SUM(install.lifee) as lb,SUM(install.tfee) as tt,SUM(install.enrfee) as enr,SUM(install.refee) as re,SUM(install.spofee) as spo,SUM(install.exfee) as ex FROM stu JOIN install ON install.sid=stu.sid Where install.sid='".$row['sid']."' AND install.curem=$sem AND stu.curem=$sem AND stu.baid=$batch AND install.paid=1");
        $result[] = $querys->result_array();
}

return $result;
    }
```

Controller

```
    public function searchsubmit()
{
        $batch=$this->input->post('srch');
        $sem=$this->input->post('srch1');
        $data['result']=$this->law_model->schbysempaid($batch, $sem);
        $this->load->view('admission/dashboard',$data);
}
```

View

```
foreach($result as $paid){
<td><?php echo $paid['am'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['lb'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['tt'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['spo'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['ex'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['enr'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $paid['re'] ?></td>
}
```

Comment: please give full error. So I can understand properly

Comment: I just want to know what is undefined..? I mean which variable is undefined.?

Comment: Undefined Index:am <?php echo $paid['am'] ?> and so on

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only one row because in your model your **return** statement is inside the loop, so after the first iteration the data is returned. Try placing the return statement after the loop.

```
public function schbysempaid($batch, $sem){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE curem=$sem AND baid=$batch");
    $temp_arr = array();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $querys=$this->db->query("SELECT SUM(install.adfee) as am,SUM(install.lifee) as lb,SUM(install.tfee) as tt,SUM(install.enrfee) as enr,SUM(install.refee) as re,SUM(install.spofee) as spo,SUM(install.exfee) as ex FROM stu JOIN install ON install.sid=stu.sid Where install.sid='".$row['sid']."' AND install.curem=$sem AND stu.curem=$sem AND stu.baid=$batch AND install.paid=1");
        array_push($temp_arr , $querys->result_array());
    }
    return $temp_arr;
}
```